# How can I detect state of boostrap slider?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-slider

I am using this library :
https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider

I have my slider:

```
<input id="months" data-slider-id='monthsSlider' type="text" data-slider-min="5" data-slider-max="10" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="5" data-slider-handle="square" />
```

How can I detect when user clicks on slider handle and move it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Here**](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider#events) are the `Events`.

> **Events**
>
> **slide**
>   This event fires when the slider is dragged
>
> **slideStart**
>   This event fires when
>   dragging start
>
> **slideStop** 
>   This event fires when the dragging stops or has been clicked on
>
> **change**
>   This event fires when the slider value has changed
>
> **slideEnabled**
>   This event
>   fires when the slider is enabled
>
> **slideDisabled**
>
> This event fires
>   when the slider is disabled

so, you can use:-

```
$('#months').on('slide', function(slideEvt) {
    var newValue = slideEvt.value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is include their file to your page. rest will be taken care of as defined in their example page :

```
###################
       HTML
###################

<input id="ex1" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="14"/>



###################
    JavaScript
###################

// With JQuery
$('#ex1').slider({
    formatter: function(value) {
        return 'Current value: ' + value;
    }
});

// Without JQuery
var slider = new Slider('#ex1', {
    formatter: function(value) {
        return 'Current value: ' + value;
    }
});


###################
       CSS
###################

#ex1Slider .slider-selection {
    background: #BABABA;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the event [`slide`](http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/) (Example 6)

```js
$('#ex6').slider({
  formatter: function(value) {
    return 'Current value: ' + value;
  }
}).on('slide', function() {
  $('#ex6SliderVal').html(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/6.0.13/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/6.0.13/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>

<input id="ex6" type="text" data-slider-min="-5" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="3" />
<span id="ex6CurrentSliderValLabel">Current Slider Value: <span id="ex6SliderVal">3</span></span>
```